# How do I test an exception being raised in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am trying to write an unit test to test a part of a method. I am trying to test the part where an Exception is thrown and a LoggableException is reraised. For the unittest to force an Exception thrown, I patch logging.info to throw an Exception.

The current behavior is

- patched function throws an Exception (correct)
- the Exception is caught and LoggableException is thrown (correct)
- function terminates and Exception is raised (incorrect)
- the except block is not triggered (incorrect)
- unit test fails

The intended behavior is

- patched Exception to be raised
- patched Exception caught and LoggableException raised
- function terminates and unittest catches Loggable exception
- unit test pass

My code is as follows (extracted from a larger piece of code):

`util.py` (Cannot modify)

```
class LoggableException(BaseException):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.message = kwargs['message']
```

`work.py` (cannot modify)

```
import logging

from util import LoggableException
import logging

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)

    def cat_work(self):
        try:
            logging.info("hi there")
        except Exception as ex:
            # addl. stuff
            raise LoggableException(message='cat was here')
```

`test.py` (I can change all I want)

```
from util import LoggableException
from work import Server
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

class TestingWork:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = Server()

    def test_cat_work_thing(self):
        with patch("logging.info", Mock(side_effect=Exception())):
            try:
                self.server.cat_work()
                assert False
            except LoggableException:
                print("Caught the correct exception")
            except Exception:
                print("Caught the wrong exception")

tests = TestingWork()
tests.test_cat_work_thing()
```

Output

```
[Running] python3 -u "/Users/sudomeacat/Dev/experimental/mock_testing/tests.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sudomeacat/Dev/experimental/mock_testing/work.py", line 12, in cat_work
    logging.info("hi there")
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 1093, in __call__
    return self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 1097, in _mock_call
    return self._execute_mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/unittest/mock.py", line 1152, in _execute_mock_call
    raise effect
Exception

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sudomeacat/Dev/experimental/mock_testing/tests.py", line 18, in <module>
    tests.test_cat_work_thing()
  File "/Users/sudomeacat/Dev/experimental/mock_testing/tests.py", line 12, in test_cat_work_thing
    self.server.cat_work()
  File "/Users/sudomeacat/Dev/experimental/mock_testing/work.py", line 15, in cat_work
    raise LoggableException(msg='cat was here', word='not really')
  File "/Users/sudomeacat/Dev/experimental/mock_testing/util.py", line 3, in __init__
    self.msg = kwargs['message']
KeyError: 'message'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.122 seconds
```

Comment: Um, `raise LoggableException(msg='cat was here', word='not really')` is wrong to begin with since `LoggableException` expects a `message` kwarg, not `msg`..? Or is that what you're trying to test..?

Comment: That's a typo lol

Comment: Well, that's what's causing your output.

Comment: Well, I am a dummy sometimes haha. Thank you for that!

Meanwhile, what do I do with the post?

Comment: Running the code you've pasted just prints out "Caught the correct exception" for me now. (Also, your "output" block no longer matches your code.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assert the raise of the exception, with `unittest` you can do it like `with self.assertRaises`.

In your case you can extend your test class from `unittest.TestCase` and do:

```
   with self.assertRaises(LoggableException):
        self.server.cat_work()
```